# Get an object's memory address as a long/long long?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

What I need is pretty straightforward :

The same way we can `NSLog("%@",someObject);` or `NSString* Hex = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%p",someObject];` to print the *hex* value of `someObject`'s memory address, I want to get it into a number variable (to use it as a unique identifier).

Any idea how this could be done? Any built-in methods?

Comment: Yeah, it's a simple cast.  But there be dragons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Others showed how to get the integer value of an adress, I want to add som considarations.

As long as the object lives, the pointer is already unique. and as sson, as a object get's deallocated, there is no use for an unique identifier derived from the pointer anymore. infact it might do harm, if you have an identifier to an allocated object which address is already re-used.

better keep track of an object by adding it to some collection or adding a guaranteed unique id to the object itself. [UUIDs](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_Unique_Identifier) are a good choice for that.

an implementation for that:

```
-(NSString *)uuid
{
    CFUUIDRef uuid = CFUUIDCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault);
    NSString *uuidStr = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)CFUUIDCreateString(kCFAllocatorDefault, uuid);
    CFRelease(uuid);
    return uuidStr;
}
```

Answer (score 12):

You don't need any "methods". You're looking for the cast operator:

```
uintptr_t pointer_as_integer = (uintptr_t)someObject;
```

**But you should really not do this.**

Comment: why not? what are the problems?

Comment: @PeterLapisu, because it is not integer, it is a pointer. Try to print it in console and you will see something like this: <__NSMallocBlock__: 0x105731e0>. Thinking about it as an integer can lead to crashes due to wrong memory access.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to look at the `-(NSUInteger)hash` method on NSObject instead. If you really want though, pointers are integers already, and hex is just a format to read an integer.

```
NSLog("%x",(int)someObject);
```

Comment: On the Intel 64-bit platform `sizeof(<pointer>) != sizeof(int)`. You loose the upper 32 bit if you just cast the pointer to an int. (That is the reason for the `uintptr_t` data type.)

Comment: Note that `-hash` isn't guaranteed to return a unique value for two distinct objects. The only stipulation is that if `-isEqual:` returns true for two objects, the values returned by both object's `-hash` method must be equal.

Comment: That should be `NSLog("0x%llx", someObject);` in 64-bit platform.